# Auto generate master-detail crud views based on a class in Android

Tags: android

In the same respect that ORM libraries like SugarORM have black-boxed a SQLite database operations, is there a similar library that aids in the creation of master-detail lists and edit screens based on a class?

That is, if I have a few POJOs like `Client` or `Order` as follows:

```
class Order {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    /* .. other members ..*/
    public Orders() { ... }
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

and

```
class Client {
    private String foo;
    private long bar;
    /* .. other members ..*/
    public Client() { ... }
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

For example, might there be a method to create an `EditView` from any private Strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I started a project on github to help out in creating an Android View based on a Class.

[PojoMojo](https://github.com/rgoodie/PojoMojo)